# Kio estas "Postkongresa/Postrenkontiĝa sindromo"?

Tags: culture

Mi plurfoje legis en Esperantaj babilejoj la vortoj *Postkongresa sindromo* aŭ *Postrenkontiĝa sindromo*. Kio estas tio?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ho, mi ĵus spertas ĝin.

Kiam oni estas ĉe renkontiĝo, oni ekkonas mojosulojn kaj havas bonan tempon. 
Oni parolas unu el la plej mojosaj lingvoj de la mondo. ;-)

Aliuloj trovas vin inteligenta, interesa...
Vi ekkonas homojn de la tuta mondo.

Parenteze, kongresoj estas feriaj tagoj - vi ne estas devigita labori (foje oni ne tiom multege ŝatas la labortagon...). Pro tio ke estas feriaj tagoj, oni ankaŭ estas pli libera ol dum la ĉiutaga vivo - oni povas tiom multe dormi, kiom oni volas - aŭ preskaŭ tute ne, se oni preferas tion.

Kongreso estas iomete alia mondo.

Kaj poste... Vi revenas al la realeco. Ne tiom multe da mojosuloj... Ne tiom multe da Esperantumado...

Vi ĉiuj mankas al mi!

Tio estas postkongresa sindromo.